# get top unique 10 artists by their song view count

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. `Artists`, `SongArtists`, `Songs`.

Song can have multiple artists. Therefore, I have joint table called `SongArtists` and table structure is -

Songs
`ID | Name | URL | ViewCount | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt`

Artists
`ID | Name | URL | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt`

SongArtists
`ID | SongID | ArtistID`

Song table has view_count column to store how many times the song is viewed.

I want to get top 10 artists based on their song view count.

I tried below query but same artist is shown twice.  I cannot use group by because I need to songs.view_count to sort.

```
select artists.* 
from artists 
inner join song_artists 
  on song_artists.artist_id = artists.id 
inner join songs on songs.id = song_artists.song_id 
order by songs.view_count desc 
limit 10;
```

Please show me how I can achieve.

Example Data

Songs

```
ID | Name | URL | ViewCount | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt
1 | Song A | song-a | 154 | 2021-12-11 15:34:21 | 2021-12-11 15:34:21
2 | Song B | song-b | 54 | 2021-12-13 12:23:12 | 2021-12-13 12:23:12
3 | Song C | song-c | 123 | 2021-12-13 13:12:56 | 2021-12-13 13:12:56
4 | Song D | song-d | 15 | 2021-12-13 14:01:15 | 2021-12-13 14:01:15
5 | Song E | song-e | 26 | 2021-12-14 12:12:03 | 2021-12-14 12:12:03
6 | Song F | song-f | 165 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
7 | Song G | song-g | 121 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
8 | Song H | song-h | 135 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
9 | Song I | song-i | 25 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
10 | Song J | song-j | 15 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
11 | Song K | song-k | 26 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
12 | Song L | song-l | 5 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
```

Artists

```
ID | Name | URL | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt
1 | Artist A | artist-a | 2021-12-11 15:34:21 | 2021-12-11 15:34:21
2 | Artist B | artist-b | 2021-12-13 12:23:12 | 2021-12-13 12:23:12
3 | Artist C | artist-c | 2021-12-13 13:12:56 | 2021-12-13 13:12:56
4 | Artist D | artist-d | 2021-12-13 14:01:15 | 2021-12-13 14:01:15
5 | Artist E | artist-e | 2021-12-14 12:12:03 | 2021-12-14 12:12:03
6 | Artist F | artist-f | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
7 | Artist G | artist-g | 2021-12-11 15:34:21 | 2021-12-11 15:34:21
8 | Artist H | artist-h | 2021-12-13 12:23:12 | 2021-12-13 12:23:12
9 | Artist I | artist-i | 2021-12-13 13:12:56 | 2021-12-13 13:12:56
10 | Artist J | artist-j | 2021-12-13 14:01:15 | 2021-12-13 14:01:15
11 | Artist K | artist-k | 2021-12-14 12:12:03 | 2021-12-14 12:12:03
12 | Artist L | artist-l | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
```

SongAritsts

```
ID | SongID | ArtistID
1 | 1 | 3
2 | 2 | 2
3 | 3 | 1
4 | 4 | 10
5 | 5 | 11
6 | 6 | 12
7 | 7 | 9
8 | 8 | 8
9 | 9 | 7
10 | 10 | 6
11 | 11 | 5
12 | 12 | 4
13 | 12 | 1
```

Results Expected

```
ID | Name | URL | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt
12 | Artist L | artist-l | 2021-12-14 13:54:23 | 2021-12-14 13:54:23
3 | Artist C | artist-c | 2021-12-13 13:12:56 | 2021-12-13 13:12:56
8 | Artist H | artist-h | 2021-12-13 12:23:12 | 2021-12-13 12:23:12
1 | Artist A | artist-a | 2021-12-11 15:34:21 | 2021-12-11 15:34:21
9 | Artist I | artist-i | 2021-12-13 13:12:56 | 2021-12-13 13:12:56
2 | Artist B | artist-b | 2021-12-13 12:23:12 | 2021-12-13 12:23:12
11 | Artist K | artist-k | 2021-12-14 12:12:03 | 2021-12-14 12:12:03
5 | Artist E | artist-e | 2021-12-14 12:12:03 | 2021-12-14 12:12:03
7 | Artist G | artist-g | 2021-12-11 15:34:21 | 2021-12-11 15:34:21
10 | Artist J | artist-j | 2021-12-13 14:01:15 | 2021-12-13 14:01:15
```

Comment: You tagged Laravel but are showing us a raw SQL statement? Is there a reason you're not using query builder?

Comment: Add the song title to your results.  It will tell you why.  The same artist has multiple songs in teh top 10.

Comment: It would be much easier if you provide table description and some data examples with expected results

Comment: you could `1` groupBy with artist and then `2` sum the songs and then `3` orderBy descending sum of songs and finnally `4` limit 10. I just didn't see the answer of Bill Karwin before writing my comment, he has said exactly what I am trying to tell

Comment: Can you share the models and relationship code.

Comment: @ErgestBasha hi, i added table description, samples and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
select artists.*,t1.view_count 
from artists   
inner join (select artists.name, songs.view_count
            from artists 
            inner join song_artists  on song_artists.artist_id = artists.id 
            inner join songs on songs.id = song_artists.song_id 
            order by songs.view_count desc limit 10
           ) as t1 on t1.name=artists.name
order by view_count desc    ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    name          url              createdAt        updatedAt     view_count
> 12    Artist L    artist-l    2021-12-14 13:54:23 2021-12-14 13:54:23 165
> 3 Artist C    artist-c    2021-12-13 13:12:56 2021-12-13 13:12:56 154
> 8 Artist H    artist-h    2021-12-13 12:23:12 2021-12-13 12:23:12 135
> 1 Artist A    artist-a    2021-12-11 15:34:21 2021-12-11 15:34:21 123
> 9 Artist I    artist-i    2021-12-13 13:12:56 2021-12-13 13:12:56 121
> 2 Artist B    artist-b    2021-12-13 12:23:12 2021-12-13 12:23:12 54
> 5 Artist E    artist-e    2021-12-14 12:12:03 2021-12-14 12:12:03 26
> 11    Artist K    artist-k    2021-12-14 12:12:03 2021-12-14 12:12:03 26
> 7 Artist G    artist-g    2021-12-11 15:34:21 2021-12-11 15:34:21 25
> 6 Artist F    artist-f    2021-12-14 13:54:23 2021-12-14 13:54:23 15
> ```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1772083455984557edf0b6aa7d03b5a9

**

> Edit: @Lwin Htoo Ko below answer gave the desired result

**

```
select artists.* 
from artists 
inner join ( 
             select artists.id, 
                    songs.view_count 
             from artists 
             inner join song_artists on song_artists.artist_id = artists.id 
             inner join songs on songs.id = song_artists.song_id 
             group by artists.id, songs.view_count 
             order by songs.view_count desc 
             ) as top_artists on top_artists.id = artists.id 
group by artists.id limit 10;
```

Comment: Your answer still gave me duplicate artists however based on your answer I achieved what I wanted.  Therefore, I selected your answer.

`select artists.* from artists inner join (select artists.id, songs.view_count from artists inner join song_artists on song_artists.artist_id = artists.id inner join songs on songs.id = song_artists.song_id group by artists.id, songs.view_count order by songs.view_count desc) as top_artists on top_artists.id = artists.id group by artists.id limit 10;`

Comment: @LwinHtooKo I'm glad it helped, I edited the answer and added the query that gave you the correct answer so it might help  others who might face the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can still sort by the artist's `MAX(view_count)` if you use group by:

```
select artists.* 
from artists 
inner join song_artists 
  on song_artists.artist_id = artists.id 
inner join songs on songs.id = song_artists.song_id 
group by artists.<primary key>
order by MAX(songs.view_count) desc 
limit 10;
```

That will reduce the results to one row per artist, and sort by the `view_count` of their most-viewed song.

I used `<primary key>` in the example, but you would use `id` or whatever is the primary key of your table. In recent versions of MySQL, this is enough to cue the query parser that the other columns of `artists` are functionally dependent on the grouping column(s).